# Migrating to v1 metadata server endpoint. Identify Processes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

We need to find the the processes that uses v1beta metadata server endpoint.

Documentation: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/migrating-to-v1-metadata-server?authuser=1

As per the documentation to find processes I am using both ngrep and auditd to crosscheck.

ngrep is sending some result on my way.

```
GET /computeMetadata/v1beta1/instance/id HTTP/1.1..Host: metadata.goog..User-Agent: curl/7.52.1..Accept: */*....
```

and when I try to list down the processes, I do not get process with the resulted post (the process might end before the query trigger)

```
COMMAND         PID USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
google_network_ 798 root    7u  IPv4 1674967626      0t0  TCP 10.128.0.4:44876->169.254.169.254:80 (ESTABLISHED)
google_accounts 805 root    5u  IPv4 1674980506      0t0  TCP 10.128.0.4:44878->169.254.169.254:80 (ESTABLISHED)
google_clock_sk 809 root    5u  IPv4 1674982496      0t0  TCP 10.128.0.4:44880->169.254.169.254:80 (ESTABLISHED)
google_clock_sk 809 root    6u  IPv4 1674914460      0t0  TCP 10.128.0.4:44874->169.254.169.254:80 (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

But the auditd does not result in any processes.
I am not able to find any processes which may use the v1beta endpoint.

Comment: As per the [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/migrating-to-v1-metadata-server?authuser=1#find-vm), you need to identify the VM(or [GKE nodes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/protecting-cluster-metadata?authuser=1#identify-legacy-apis)) first before running the commands to identify the process. The 'ps' command can be used to gather more information. And after gather necessary information, you need to follow the [step:2](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/migrating-to-v1-metadata-server?authuser=1#migration_overview) to complete the migration  process.

Comment: I already found the VMs. But step 2 is where I am getting the trouble. I am not able to pin point the processes. That is the whole problem